# How to edit android edittext value by terminal?

Tags: java, android, linux, unix

I know, we can start app activity by some commands .

eg:

`$ adb shell am start -n com.google.android.contacts/.ContactsActivity`

Can I change `edittext` value by terminal emulator then go to second action (click button).

Or Can I add inputs to activity by other apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `EditText` that you want to type is has focus, you can use

```
adb shell input text "Hello world!"
```

**UPDATE**
If you also want to use click action you could try

```
adb shell input touch <x, y>
```

You will need the exact coordinates of the `View` you want to press

Comment: I want add value and click action also .

Comment: Updated answer, I don't understand what you mean by 'add value edittext by other application'